# Problem with incorrect polygon - Postgis query doesn't work

Tags: gis, postgis

Well, I have 2 tables, one represents polygons and the second points. I want to know 2 things, the first is the area of the polygons of the first table, the second is the area of the intersection between 2 geometries:
1) the area of the polygons of the first table
2) the area of the union of a buffer of 150 meters radius around my points that is situated inside the polygons.

I made the query to do it, but something went wrong because if I set the `WHERE` clause to select just one of the polygons of the first table then all works fine, but if I want the data of all polygons, then I get the error: "Error performing intersection: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 12.20304662098798 46.117661703823636 at 12.20304662098798 46.117661703823636"

The first query that works is :

```
SELECT residenziali.code,
       ST_Area(residenziali.the_geom::geography, true) as area_zona, 
       ST_Area(ST_Intersection(residenziali.the_geom, 
               (ST_Union(ST_Buffer(fermate.the_geom::geography, 150)::geometry)))::geography,true) as intersect 
 FROM residenziali 
 JOIN fermate ON st_contains(residenziali.the_geom , fermate.the_geom) 
WHERE residenziali.id = '969' 
GROUP BY residenziali.code,residenziali.the_geom
```

when I remove the `WHERE` clause it doesn't work anymore, what is the error??

the geometry column of both tables is "the_geom", the first table is "residenziali" and the second is "fermate", both using WGS84. Thanks!!!

Comment: Check to make sure you have no geometry errors in either table.  What does "SELECT ST_IsValid(the_geom) FROM residenziali" and "SELECT ST_IsValid(the_geom) FROM fermate" give you?

Comment: It is unlikely to be that. It is more likely to be artefacts of unioning buffers returning some non-polygon types

Comment: @sovemp you were right, I had a few poligons with some errors and postgis cannot calculate the area. I opened it with qgis and adjust it. Thanks a lo for your help!! There are no many people that have the knowledge of the gis world. Thanks again!!

Comment: @user3868481. Actually, there are a plenty of people with GIS knowledge, but it is expected that you start with valid polygons before posting a question like this. In future, use ST_IsValid or ST_MakeValid first.